# how do you use Expression Web 2 and Visual Studio asp.net mvc together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just wondering what the best way to incorporate it in a asp.net mvc project so that the design can be done using expression web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has publicly stated that they plan to incorporate ASP.NET MVC into Expression Web in the future.